# Intersection of two semiorthogonal decompositions on a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety, and $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two smooth divisors on it meeting each other normally. Suppose that $D^b_{E_1}(X) \subset D^b(X)$ and $D^b_{E_2}(X) \subset D^b(X)$ are admissible subcategories, so that there are semiorthogonal decompositions
$$ D^b(X)=\langle D^b_{E_1}(X)^{\perp}, D^b_{E_1}(X) \rangle $$
and 
$$ D^b(X)=\langle D^b_{E_2}(X)^{\perp}, D^b_{E_2}(X) \rangle $$.

Is then $D^b_{E_1\cap E_2}(X) \subset D^b_{E_i}(X)$ admissible?

Or is there any further condition that can guarantee this?

Comment: What is $D^b_{E_1}(X)$?

Comment: I meant $D^b_{E_i}(X)$ to be the full subcategory of $D^b(X)$ of complexes of sheaves whose cohomology sheaves have their support contained in $E_i$.

Comment: It is never admissible.

Comment: 1. Can you explain this a bit to me?

2. What if I replace $D^b_{Z}(X)$ with $D^b(Z)$ everywhere in the question?

Comment: It is also not admissible.